# Is it possible to create such C++ macros that would wrap your standard (inherited) class into an application?

Tags: c++, class, macros, cross-platform, shared-libraries

So we have simple interface base class:

```
class animal {
public:
  animal(int age) : age_(age) {
  }
  virtual ~animal(void) {
  }
  virtual std::string get_name(void) {
    return "A generic animal";
  }
  int get_age(void) {
    return age_;
  }
protected:
  int age_;
};
```

And we want ti inherit from it with a class like this:

```
#include "animal.hpp"
#include "some_includes_for_our_shared_libs.hpp"

class puma : public animal {
 public:
  puma(int age) : animal(age) {}
  virtual std::string get_name() {
    return "puma";
  }
};
```

If we are creating a library - shared or static its `ok` for us just to inherit from it, but when we want to create an application we'd have to create a some main function and probably add some includes. I want to create some macros that would allow me to create such main in case class is compiled not into shared library.

I hepe it could look like

```
// puma.cpp
#include "FILE_WITH_MACROS.hpp"
ANIMAL_MACROS_NAME_HERE class puma : public animal {
 public:
  puma(int age) : animal(age) {}
  virtual std::string get_name() {
    return "puma";
  }
};
//end of puma.cpp
```

And that macros would get class name and create a main that would create and call our class as if it was calling general animall class or just add includes for `"animal.hpp"` and `"some_includes_for_our_shared_libs.hpp"` .

So in case of shared lib class would be turned by macros into

```
#include "animal.hpp"
#include "some_includes_for_our_shared_libs.hpp"

class puma : public animal {
 public:
  puma(int age) : animal(age) {}
  virtual std::string get_name() {
    return "puma";
  }
};
```

And in case of application class would be turned by macros into

```
#include <iostream>
#include "animal.hpp"


class puma : public animal {
 public:
  puma(int age) : animal(age) {}
  virtual std::string get_name() {
    return "puma";
  }
};

int main()
{
int default_age = 4;
puma *an_animal = new puma(default_age);
std::cout << "anmal "<< an_animal->get_name << " created. Its age is " << an_animal->get_age << std::endl;
std::cin.get();
}
```

Usage: imagine we have a `service-base` class and we created `new-service`.  Our main server app supports extensions so `new-service` can be connected to it in cese it is compiled into shared library. But what If we want to make our service into a stand alone server? than we would need such macros to wrap it with `main` and possibly add or remove some `#includes`.

my point is to make it so that any class that inherits from my special interface could me compiled into shared library or exequtable with out any code changes.

Comment: "standarD" with a terminal `D`, even in German! :-)

Comment: Why can you not separate the code cleanly into `puma.cpp` and `puma.h`, which would be independent of your compilation target, and then you just need an appropriate library and standalone source file? What you're doing looks way too high-level to me to be solved with a preprocessor macro.

Comment: Not strictly what you asked but a unit test framework might be more useful in the long run: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B

Comment: I'd say just create some utility functions to do that, instead of totally obfuscating this with error-prone hard to debug macros.

Comment: What do you mean by "compiled in"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
int default_age = 4;
SERVICECLASS *an_animal = new SERVICECLASS(default_age);
std::cout << "anmal "<< an_animal->get_name << " created. Its age is " << an_animal->get_age << std::endl;
std::cin.get();
}
```

Then compile with (your compiler's equivalent of) `-DSERVICECLASS=puma`, or have a file called something like "config.h" which is included by `main`, and that you can edit without having to edit any other code.

Then you can define your animal classes however you like. If you want to define classes like this:

```
#define STRINGIZE_(ARG) #ARG
#define EXPAND_AND_STRINGIZE(ARG) STRINGIZE(ARG)

class SERVICECLASS: public animal {
 public:
  SERVICECLASS(int age) : animal(age) {}
  virtual std::string get_name() {
    return EXPAND_AND_STRINGIZE(SERVICECLASS);
  }
};
```

then you can. But surely your classes do more than just hard-code a string, so I'd expect different animals to need separate definitions even if they have a certain amount in common.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just make it so that the `main()` is trivial. Like

```
int main()
{
    int default_age = 4;
    return puma(default_age).run();
}
```

and leave it at that.

Comment: my point is to make it so that any class that inherits from animal could me compiled into shared library or exequtable with out any code changes.