# Can C++ macros add some code to the end of C++ file?

Tags: c++, macros, cross-platform, c-preprocessor

So I have code like:

```
// puma.cpp
#include "FILE_WITH_MACROS.hpp"
ANIMAL_MACROS_NAME_HERE class puma : public animal {
 public:
  puma(int age) : animal(age) {}
  virtual std::string get_name() {
    return "puma";
  }
};
//end of puma.cpp and here we want to add some more code via ANIMAL_MACROS_NAME_HERE  macros.
```

Can my macros that I use in the middle of my C++ file add some code to the end of my file?

Comment: What would you like the macro to add in the end? Maybe there is another way of achieving what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can always add another macro in the end of the file.

In some cases it can be possible to do something like this:

```
#define MY_CLASS_WITH_END_STUFF(derived, parent) \
    ANIMAL_MACROS_NAME_HERE class derived : public parent \
    { \
    public: \
        ... \
    }; \
    // here you can add stuff now as part of the macro...
```

Then you would define the classes with the outer macro like this:

```
MY_CLASS_WITH_END_STUFF(puma, animal);
```

This can of course be extended various ways depending on needs. However, it's restricted in certain cases e.g. where the classes you want to specify vary and do not follow a simple convention which can be put in a macro.

Comment: @What would I like the macro to add in the end: please see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981860/is-it-possible-to-create-such-c-macros-that-would-wrap-your-standard-inherited). And could you provide how to use your macro from code?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm very much mistaken, I'm afraid not. C macros are pretty minimal in their capabilities. Is there any particular reason you can't have the macro generate code *before* `puma`'s declaration?

Answer (score 1):

No. Macros expand inline where the preprocessor encounters them in your source file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add it if you only have `ANIMAL_MACROS_NAME_HERE` before your class name. You would need to add another symbol at the bottom of your file that would expand into the extra code you want.