# What are defines on different platforms (windows, mac, linux) that can tell your code that is it part of an application, not a library?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, c-preprocessor

So I wonder how my code that can be included into different projects can find out if it is included into library of application? (on Linux, Mac and Windows)

Comment: none - AFAIK - why does your code care?

Comment: So you want some `#define` that tells you whether the code is being compiled into a exectuable or into a library? And why?

Comment: I want such define for example to solve [this=)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981860/is-it-possible-to-create-such-c-macros-that-would-wrap-your-standard-inherited)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that it can't.  The decision whether an object file
(generated by the compiler) is part of a library or part of the
application isn't made until link time (and aren't libraries part of the 
application?).

Comment: Well... shared-libraries can be connected to your app on fly so they are more plugins than real parts of app...

Comment: @Kabumbus Some are, some aren't; one possible use of shared libraries is to be able to update your application on the fly.  But the real problem is simple: the same object file can be linked once into an application, and another time into a shared library.  So any test would have to be at runtime.